# adding every 2 numbers of the array together. Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
myList = [1.32412694112, 1.2904242732, 0.59030181, 0.5741011728, 0.6093767538, 0.5832783666, 0.5674657211999999, 0.5775693444]
```

I want to reduce the length of `myList` by adding some of the items.

```
 myList = [2.61455121432, 1.1644029828, 1.1926551204, 1.14503506559]
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: sorry i'll edit

Comment: I find it clear enought. you want to be adding every 2 numbers together ( 1+2, 3+4,5+6,7+8

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've made a simple way to do it. There are more "clean" ways to do it, but I want to keep it simple so it's easier to learn from it.

```
var myList = [1.32412694112, 1.2904242732, 0.59030181, 0.5741011728, 0.6093767538, 0.5832783666, 0.5674657211999999, 0.5775693444];
var n = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i += 2) {
  n.push(myList[i] + myList[i + 1]);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var myList = [1.32412694112, 1.2904242732, 0.59030181, 0.5741011728, 0.6093767538, 0.5832783666, 0.5674657211999999, 0.5775693444];
var n = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i += 2) {
  n.push(myList[i] + myList[i + 1]);
}

console.log(n)
```